# Loops in coffeescript with operations

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How can I convert this loop to coffeescript?

```
for (var j = world.m_jointList; j; j = j.m_next) {
        drawJoint(j, context);
}
```

Comment: I dont even understand this javascript loop anyways, could someone explain it while answering the coffeescript part?

Answer (score 2):

```
while j = (unless j? then first else j.next)
  do stuff
```

But generally, what's wrong with just writing `for` loops with the initialize code as a separate statement, e.g. `j=first; while j then ...; j=j.next`?

**edit:**
Or, possibly:

```
while j = j?.next ? first
  do stuff
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! I'm using it for a Box2D [Joint List](http://kyucon.com/doc/box2d/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.html#GetJointList())

Answer (score 1):

What's happening in the original:

Javascript has [compound *for* loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Kinds_of_for_loops). The declaration inside the parenthesis has three expressions: `for(x; y; z){...}`.

- `x` runs once before the loop
- `y` is a condition, tested before each iteration. If it's false the loop will stop
- `z` runs once after every iteration

In this code, you set `j = world.m_jointList`, which is the first item in the linked list. The middle part of the `for` loop is checking for [thruthiness](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) of `j;`, and after each iteration `j` is set to `j.m_next`, which is a pointer to the next object in the chain. It ends when `j` evaluates to false (probably `undefined` in this case).

To visualize that, `world` could look like this:

```
world = {
   m_jointList: {
      value: 'head',
      m_next: world.foo1
   },
   foo1: {
      value: 'foo',
      m_next: world.foo2
   },
   foo2: {
      value: 'foo',
      m_next: world.tail
   },
   tail: {
      value: 'foo'
   }
}
```

In reality the items in the list probably don't exist as properties of `world`, but this would work the same. Notice that `m_next` is undefined in the last object. Sometimes a placeholder value for the tail will be used indicating the end of the chain.

The name `m_jointList` is also a bit misleading here because it doesn't actually contain the list, just the first element of it.

This should do it in coffeescript:

```
j = world.m_jointList
while j then drawJoint(j, context); j = j.m_next
```

And that would've been a good use of `do...while` in javascript:

```
var j = world.m_jointList
do { drawJoint(j, context) } while (j = j.m_next)
```

Comment: @island205 I was thinking of `do...while` :/ fixed.

Comment: but do...while like this `do{alert("foo");}while(false);` could exec at least once.

Comment: your `while j then drawJoint(j, context); j = j.m_next` is the best!

Comment: @island205 from the context available, I'd guess an empty list wouldn't be allowed to exist (or get to the drawing routine). That decision is left to the dev in charge :)

Comment: Ah, and in my previous code I was actually skipping the first element. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is the best:

```
j = world.m_jointList
loop
    break if not j
    drawJoint j,context
    j=j.m_next
```

it just describes what the `for` loop mean.

Comment: I would use `while j?` instead of the loop-break syntax.